# PHP as Javascript, GET Parameter

Tags: javascript, php

I have a file `javascript.php` which is inserted into my PHP File like this

```
$data = array(...Some parameters...);
echo '<script src="path/to/file/javascript.php?'.http_build_query($data).'" type="text/javascript"></script>'."\n";
```

The javascript.php file looks like this:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/javascript'); ?>

$(window).load(function() {
    alert('Loaded: <? $_GET['someparameter'] ?>');
});
```

But it only alerts `Loaded:` nothing with the `$_GET`.

What did I do wrong, how can I get the Parameters of the URI?

Comment: escape, escape, escape

Comment: <?=$_GET['someparameter'] ?> or <? echo $_GET['someparameter'] ?>

Comment: $_GET is aserver side variable, that you`re trying to catch on a brosser side. parse it to javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead using:

```
alert('Loaded: <? $_GET['someparameter'] ?>');
```

use like this:

```
alert('Loaded: <?php echo $_GET['someparameter'] ?>');
```

Comment: Thanks, totally missed that. Sometimes you just get blind of all the code

Answer (score 1):

You've missed the `=`.

```
<?=$_GET['someparameter'] ?>
```

Comment: Does the `=` stand for echo?

Comment: Its alternative to `<?php echo`.